# Label Content binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a label, whose content I would like to bind to a bool. I also have a a BoolToStringConverter, which converts 0 to "No", and 1 to "Yes".

So basically the content of the label display changes between "Yes" or "No", depending on the bool variable is 1 or 0;

I am wondering how I should write this binding xaml code? Something like this?

```
 <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />       

  <Label  Content="{Binding boolVar, Converter={MyConverter boolVar}}" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding boolVar, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

Do know that if you choose, you could do this without a converter too. Something like:

```
<Label>
  <Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="Content"
              Value="Yes" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Item}"
                     Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Content"
                  Value="No" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

[Download link for both methods](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpxfaryw150luc0/BoolToString.rar)